# How to determine the design of shareable link for my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta

I am trying to change the design of my website's link that appears when I share it "http://www.example.com" ( share it as a post on facebook, twitter, linkedin...)

I was trying to add some meta feature in , but nothing change.

```
  <meta property="og:title" content=""/>
  <meta property="og:image" content=""/>
  <meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
  <meta property="og:description" content=""/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this open graph meta:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="500">
```

Comment: nothing changes .. I open "facebook debug", these errors appear: 

Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Missing Properties
The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id
SSL Error
Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will cause browser warnings) or it is invalid.

Comment: It seems you are not passing the others required meta. You have to add a content in the og:image tag

Comment: the content exits

Comment: It seems not from your error: The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id. Can you please give me the link?

Comment: sure...https://neotic.ai/

Comment: You have this bug: <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://https://neotic.ai/static/img/home.jpg"/>, remove one https. Also there is an SSL error, try to remove the https protocol, unless you have a redirect from http to https.

Comment: Also, add a / at the end of the tag.